# Rotor Replaced and MY Car is only 3 years old

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, brake-pad

I went to pep boys because i heard squealing and my pads were worn down. he also told me that i needed to replace my rotors so not knowing anything i did but i asked them tog ive them to me so i could make sure they were not screwing me over and they did.  i had 2 mechanics look at them and they said they did not need to be replaced yet.  can you guys look at them and tell me if i have been taken?[image]

Comment: In case you've never seen one before, a micrometer is just a measuring tool with two adjustable fingers. It tells you exactly how far apart those finger tips are. There's nothing wrong with asking "exactly what was the reading on the micrometer?"  From the answers and comments, it seems like you've replaced some rotors a bit ahead of schedule (but not crazy early). Your brakes should feel great, too!

Comment: *"...only 3 years old"* doesn't tell us much. Is that 3 years of 70k miles/year for a travelling salesman? Or 3 years of 10-12k miles/year for an average (American) Joe or Mary? It **really** matters.

Comment: And even mileage isn't necessarily useful. Actual braking frequency will be more important. In a lot of freeway commuting, I see brake lights coming on in many other cars much more frequently than needed. Following too closely, for example, can lead to extra braking, especially in heavy traffic.

Answer (score 10):

The only way to know if a rotor needs to be replaced is measuring it with a micrometer and comparing that to the manufacturers specifications, so, no, we can't tell you if it needed to be replaced.

However, since this was your first brake job I seriously doubt they needed to be replaced.  Common practices is to "turn" rotors when doing a brake job.  The turning process is putting it into a special machine that cuts off the surface layer of the disk, creating a smooth surface again.  This normally removes only a very small amount of material and rotors can usually be turned several times.

If you let the brakes go so far that the metal backing of the brake pads made huge grooves in the rotor, they may not be turntable, but other mechanics said they were ok, so that's not the case.  Also, if the rotors were warped (steering wheel shaking while braking, so you would know if they were warped), then sometimes they can't be turned and will have to be replaced.  Well, you can turn them, but they can quickly re-warp.

So, in summary, I'd ask the service manager *why* they needed to be replaced, because with the limited information available, I don't see a need (and more importantly, neither did the other mechanics that you asked in person -- I'd trust them over me, but this "technical" explanation is probably helpful as well).

Comment: Great add about how the machining process works.

Comment: To @Paulster2's point...  I have also replaced rotors out of laziness when doing the job myself (so I didn't have to drive to a shop), but if I was already at the shop, I would _really_ expect them to just be turned.  It really does make the rotor like new again in most cases.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments!  he said they used that tool you mentioned and said that the roters were in the orange and if he shaved them they would be in the red, but i am finding that hard to believe seeing they have never been turned before.  am i wrong?

Comment: That would be hard to believe.  If you're in the US, call around to some auto parts stores in your area to see if they turn rotors.  If they do, they can measure it and tell you what's going on.  For instance, the O'Reilly auto parts near me does this service.  That way you can easily get an informed opinion in a comfortable retail setting rather than asking another mechanic for their time.

Comment: I have to disagree.  Modern cars have pretty thin rotors and aggressive brake pads from the factory.  It's really not all that often anymore that a rotor is reusable.  If you specifically ran soft pads, you might get a second set of pads of use out of that rotor.  With OEM pads, one and done is typical.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch, I don't have the experience for a rebuttal, but that is surprising.  Are you a mechanic that gets to see these particular cases often?  Do you know when this transition to thin rotors became more mainstream?

Comment: @JPhi1618 I grew up working on cars, so my knowledge is unofficial, at best. Most vehicles made before ~1990 had non-vented rotors, meaning a solid disk of metal. Venting increases the surface area and thus heat dissipation, increasing the effectiveness of the braking action. It also reduces the lifespan, since you're asking a thinner piece of metal to do the job a solid, thicker piece was doing before. A vented surface is also subject to uneven pressures as the pad pushes against the ridges + gaps between the two plates. Driving/braking "with a lead foot" will also influence rotor longevity.

Comment: In the UK at least people stopped "turning rotors" many many years ago - personally, for the relatively small cost, I always just change pads and discs/rotors in one go.

Comment: Most micrometers have accuracy way higher than required for the job. A cheap vernier caliper is more than enough for checking the thickness of the rotor. Then you have to compare the result to rotor or car manufacturer specification. I agree that new rotors are usually cheap enough to be not worth re-machining. For example, VW Golf rotors are so cheap in the Europe that it's cheaper to get a new pair than re-machine the old parts.

Comment: Great answer until you got to the "warping" part. http://www.stoptech.com/technical-support/technical-white-papers/-warped-brake-disc-and-other-myths    Rotors are either mounted eccentric in the first place, and embed friction material unevenly as a result, or develop pad imprinting from poor break-in (overheating and then stopping with pads sitting hard on one spot on the rotor). Read the linked article carefully. Then read it again.

Comment: Happy to be corrected- what's the issue?

Comment: The issue is warping rarely, if ever, occurs on the vehicle, as I just explained, and as the article explains. The real issue with pulsating brakes is uneven friction material embedding a.k.a. pad imprinting. Rotors can be eccentric out of the box, but the real pulsation only begins once the friction material (pad transfer) builds up on the high spots. Unfortunately the industry blames brake overheating and puddles for their own incompetence- all rotors should be measured for variation in thickness and runout on installation, but it is a rare shop that does this (usually race shops).

Comment: For the record, only the first sentence of your first comment was present when I asked for explanation.  Thanks for the info, but the snark is unwarranted, and unhelpful.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot tell from *just looking at them* (in most cases) ... you have to measure the thickness of the rotor to see if they need replaced. Also, it's hard to tell from the picture how deep the wear is on the rotor. The grooves could be 1mm deep, or 5mm deep ... it's really hard to tell. It really comes down to how thick the rotors would be *after* machining.

To assuage your fears a little, most times it is only just a little more expensive to replace the rotors than to have them machined. Replacement with brand new is not a bad thing most of the time. If I do them myself, I will almost always replace over machining, just because of the time it saves me from having to take it to a shop. Since you were already at the shop, that factor isn't there.

Comment: he claimed that if he shaved them it would make them too thin.  they did use that device and they said it was in the orange and if it was in the red they would be too thin to shave.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable statement and along the lines of what I am talking about. If he did measure them, he did you right.

Answer (score 3):

Squealing can be caused by a pattern of grooves in the rotor that make it look like an old vinyl record.  The thickness of the rotor makes no difference on squealing, so even if there was plenty of meat left on the rotor it still needed servicing.  Depending on how thick the rotors were you might have been able to machine them instead of replacing them - but sometimes the cost is the same so you might as well stick with new.

Mechanics dread customer complaints about squealing brakes and many professionals will do the pads and rotors at the same to best eliminate the probability of squealing.

I just did my brakes and only replaced the pads and this resulted in squealing.  I had to go back and replace the rotors to eliminate the squealing.

If you go back to the mechanic who said the rotors were fine and told him the problem was squealing he would likely tell you to replace them.

Comment: *"Mechanics dread customer complaints about squealing brakes and many professionals will do the pads and rotors at the same to best eliminate the probability of squealing."* Big time. I got seriously tired of taking my car to the mechanic repeatedly for squealing brakes and would have been much happier to have him go for the nuclear option **much** earlier than he did.